# Angular 10: mat-sidenav is not visible

Tags: angular, angular-material

NOTE: I am using **Angular** 10.0.2 and **Angular-material**: 10.0.1 are the latest ones.

The `mat-sidenav` is not visible when I click on the `toggle (snav.toggle())` button.

Here is my ***header.component.html***

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu-icon">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()" color="accent">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <span>My App</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-links">
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary"
      matBadge="15" matBadgeSize="medium" matBadgePosition="after"
      matBadgeColor="warn">
      <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container"
  [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
  <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56" opened="true">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/accounts'"> Accounts </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/create-account'"> Create Account </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/contacts'"> Contacts </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/create-contact'"> Create Contact </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/activities'"> Activities </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/create-activity'"> Create Activity </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

***header.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;

  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

[image]

Comment: Hey, @The Rock can you please generate `https://stackblitz.com/` for that.

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya Thanks for your comment. Here is the `stackblitz` link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-sidenav-test

Comment: @TheRock https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zzdopo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css is it working for you?

Comment: @The Rock As i have seen menu is working for mobile view. so are you looking for same or desktop view also?

Comment: Hey @TheRock Please check this as i have update code and now it's working as expect [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-sidenav-test-g2jurn](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-sidenav-test-g2jurn)

Answer (score 1):

add `opened` to the `side-nav` element for testing,

then configure it as needed